How to document an external dependency from a node_modules folder in Typedoc?
I'm developing a project that is using external dependencies from a node_module within it.
Since those dependencies are part of the project, I'd like to add them to typedoc documentation, but what I get is just the string of the type declaration, not its content:
node_module/dependency/index.d.ts
export interface SomeInterface {
  propA: string
  propB: number
  propC: string
}

...

// much more content I don't want to import from typedoc

my-project index.d.ts
import { SomeInterface } from 'dependency'

export type MyType = Pick<SomeInterface, 'propA' | 'propB'>

I don't add the node_modules dependency index.d.ts to the entryPoints because it has a lot of content I don't want.
typedoc.json
{
  "$schema": "https://typedoc.org/schema.json",
  "entryPoints": [
    "./src/index.d.ts",
  ],
  "out": "api-docs"
}

Typedoc shows the string of how the type is declared, but it doesn't shows its content at all:
result in typedoc
Type alias MyType

MyType: Pick<SomeInterface, 'propA' | 'propB'>

desired result
Type alias MyType

MyType: {
  propA: string
  propB: number
}

I don't want to add the external dependency to the entryPoints of typedoc because it has a lot of information that I don't need.

Is Pick<> documented as expected with types defined in the same file? What about a type imported from a file in the same directory?

@Brother58697 Pick<> is just an example, it should work at any way. I'm not sure what you mean with type imported from a file in same directory. I tried several ways to I import the node_modules dependency, but typedoc always shows just a string of how it is used in the declaration, never its content.

I'm trying to differentiate the outcome between how a local type, a type not from node_modules, and a type from a package is documented. For the most part, I'd expect the imported types would be documented the same way regardless.

@Brother58697 I think the problem is since the node_modules dependency interface is not present in typedoc entryPoints, it doesn't have idea of how the content of that interface is, so it shows just a string of its name. And I don't have idea how to add that concrete dependency to typedoc from node_modules.

Does the same happen if foo.ts is my only entry point, and it imports the interface from bar.ts in the same directory?

Also can you edit the question to include your config?

Yes, it will never shows the content of the node_modules dependency unless it is explicitly added to the entryPoints.

My question about bar.ts is about a file right next to the entry point, not in node_modules

As soon as you add your config, we'll solve this issue.

@Brother58697 I edited the question and added the typedoc.json config.

Try commenting out the exclude property in your tsconfig.json and see if that fixes it.

@Brother58697 I don't have any exclude in the tsconfig, just include: ["src"]

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

It isn't exactly what you're looking for, but TypeDoc's @interface tag can get you close.
/** @interface */
export type MyType = Pick<SomeInterface, 'propA' | 'propB'>

This will result in TypeDoc documenting the type as if it were an interface, which will resolve all included properties.
If you really want a type alias, there is a small plugin which can be used to tell TypeDoc to document the type alias using the type which TypeScript shows when hovering over the type. This might someday be included directly in TypeDoc, but is not currently included.

That worked perfectly! It is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!
